# Conservation laws on a block with friction

Tags: momentum, energy-conservation

If a bullet strikes a block which is sitting on a table (with friction) is it correct that momentum will not be conserved because the friction is force on the system? I'm assuming that I could then use conservation of energy assuming I know the friction coefficient of the block and therefore the work done by friction. But if a question asks for the combined velocity of the block and the bullet after collision how could I answer that without knowing the distance traveled by the block and therefore the total work done by friction.
Would it be correct that the instantaneous velocity of both after collision is $v_f = \sqrt{(m1/(m1 + m2)) v_i^2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Momentum is conserved *initially*. You can use conservation of momentum to calculate how fast the block is moving immediately after the collision. Once the block starts to move, then it will start losing energy to friction.

I don't have access to the question, but from your description I would guess that you are able to calculate the friction force $\mu mg$, and using the Work-Energy theorem, you would also be able to calculate how far the block goes before all its initial kinetic energy is dissipated to friction.

Comment: Is this true with any collision? will momentum be conserved initially? or is this only true in cases where the only external force is friction since friction only acts on moving bodies?

Comment: @DanielLader the latter. If there is an external force, momentum need not be conserved.

Comment: The momentum of the center of mass is always conserved if the net external force is zero.  Here friction is an external force but is negligible during the "instantaneous" collision.

Answer (score 1):

The force of friction is negligible during the "instantaneous" collision.  Therefore, during the collision no external forces act on the bullet/block system, so momentum is conserved, and you can calculate the initial velocity of the block/bullet system just after the collision. (This is an inelastic collision so kinetic energy is not conserved; the relationship you give in your question for $v_f$ is incorrect.)

Then, the bullet/block is slowed by the force of friction.  The negative work done by friction is the decrease in the kinetic energy of the bullet/block, so you can evaluate the distance travelled to reach zero velocity.

Answer (score 1):

Mechanical energy is not conserved in an inelastic collision (heat carries away energy). So you can't use the expression you gave; you have to use conservation of momentum.

And yes, if the bullet + block is your system momentum is only conserved up until the collision. After the collision friction does work and the momentum decreases.